# "localstorage is not defined" nextjs14 "use client" running in server side

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side

I was configuring the context in Tailwind for a Next.js 14 website, and I just wanted to provide a global theme configuration for my project. So, I created the ThemeContext and added the 'use client' at the top of the file. However, it still renders on the server side and gives an error.

```
 ⨯ src\contexts\ThemeContext.tsx (22:28) @ localStorage
 ⨯ ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at eval (./src/contexts/ThemeContext.tsx:20:29)
    at ThemeProvider (./src/contexts/ThemeContext.tsx:19:78)
  20 | export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<ThemeProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  21 |     const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>(() => {
> 22 |         const storedTheme = localStorage?.getItem('theme');
     |                            ^
  23 |         return storedTheme === Theme.DARK ? Theme.DARK : Theme.LIGHT;
  24 |     });
  25 |
 ✓ Comp
```

I created a mounted state to solve the problem, but I want to understand why this is happening.

```
'use client';

...

export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<ThemeProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>(Theme.LIGHT);
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (mounted) {
            return
        }
        const storedTheme = localStorage?.getItem('theme');
        console.log("storedTheme", storedTheme)
        setTheme(storedTheme === Theme.DARK ? Theme.DARK : Theme.LIGHT);
        setMounted(true)
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!mounted) {
            return
        }
        if (theme === Theme.DARK) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
            localStorage?.setItem('theme', Theme.DARK);
        } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
            localStorage?.setItem('theme', Theme.LIGHT);
        }
    }, [theme, mounted])
```

Comment: could you provide the file structure of your codebase?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your useEffect in ThemeProvider file. Please check below updated code:-

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Check if localStorage is available (i.e., not on the server side)
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !mounted) {
      const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
      setTheme(storedTheme === Theme.DARK ? Theme.DARK : Theme.LIGHT);
      setMounted(true);
    }
  }, [mounted]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Apply theme changes to localStorage and document
    if (mounted) {
      if (theme === Theme.DARK) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', Theme.DARK);
      } else {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', Theme.LIGHT);
      }
    }
  }, [theme, mounted]);
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the component was not yet mounted and you had already called the `localstorage` object, the `localstorage` object is specific to the browser and we access it via the `window` object (`window.localstorage`), and to access this object you must be sure that the component is already mounted.

This is where the `useEffect` comes in, `useEffect` is called immediately after the first rendering, so this is the best place to call the `localstorage` object because we are sure at this level that the `window` object exists.

There is no need to check if the component is mounted in `useEffect`, it will always be the case.